# How do I combine these two Inner Join queries

Tags: mysql

How do I combine these two queries?

```
SELECT characters.name Name,characters.image Image,matchups.char1wins Char1Wins,matchups.char2wins Char2wins,matchups.draws Draws
FROM characters INNER JOIN matchups
ON (char1=6 ) WHERE (  characters.ID = matchups.char2 )

SELECT characters.name Name,characters.image Image,matchups.char1wins Char1Wins,matchups.char2wins Char2wins,matchups.draws Draws
FROM characters INNER JOIN matchups
ON (char2=6) WHERE ( characters.ID = matchups.char1 )
```

Comment: what is char1 and char2?

Comment: WHERE c.ID IN(m.char1,m.char2 )

Answer (score 0):

```
Select characters.name Name,characters.image Image,matchups.char1wins 
       Char1Wins,matchups.char2wins Char2wins,matchups.draws Draws
From characters 
Inner Join matchups On (char1=6 ) And (char2=6) 
Where (characters.ID = matchups.char2)
```

Comment: It's always better to include some explanation rather than just having a code-only answer as that makes it more useful to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT characters.name Name,characters.image Image,matchups.char1wins Char1Wins,matchups.char2wins Char2wins,matchups.draws Draws
FROM characters INNER JOIN matchups
ON (table1.common_field=table.common field) WHERE (  characters.ID = matchups.char2 OR characters.ID = matchups.char1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT characters.name Name,characters.image Image,matchups.char1wins Char1Wins,
matchups.char2wins Char2wins,matchups.draws Draws
FROM characters INNER JOIN matchups
ON (char1=6 AND characters.ID = matchups.char2 ) OR
(char2=6 AND characters.ID = matchups.char1 )
```

Comment: While this answer may solve the question, please explain the logic behind it. Just pasting some code is not going to help or be so intuitive for new developers.

Comment: No that's fine. it helps me understand the language.
When I first got into JOINS, I didn't know what in the language was accessible.
The fact that I can see "AND" and "OR" means tells me that they are accessible in combination with "ON". I did not know this before.

Comment: @NoahWatchmaker did the above query gives you the expected result?

Comment: @jophab YES it worked perfectly. before I was doing the following and it kept including the character I didn't want it to include and it was doing it MULTIPLE times. your solution worked perfectly. I thought "ON" was some different type of MySQL condition statement


   $query = "SELECT characters.name Name,characters.image  Image,matchups.char1wins Char1Wins,matchups.char2wins   Char2wins,matchups.draws Draws
    FROM characters INNER JOIN matchups
    ON (char1=$charID || char2=$charID) WHERE ( characters.ID = matchups.char1 || characters.ID = matchups.char2 ) ";

Comment: @NoahWatchmaker Feel free to upvote and mark as correct

Answer (score -1):

```
    SELECT column_name(s)
      FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
        ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;
```